# Reuse UI for smartphones and tablets using PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile-application

When developing mobile apps using PhoneGap for smartphones and tablets, how to reuse most of the UI code? The reason why I am asking is the UI layout for smartphones apps and tablets will need to be different due to the difference in their screen sizes.

I would really like to know what your recommendation is so that I can take as much advantage of using PhoneGap as possible. Thank you for your guidance in advance.

Framework I am considering to use are:

PhoneGap
jQuery Mobile
Backbone.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While We deal with the UI design in hybrid applications in Phonegap, using css techniques is a simple and good option. I have some links to share with you, which is worth reading and will be helpful in solving your problem,

[link 1](http://www.cameronmoll.com/archives/000577.html) : Mobile Web Design: Tips & Techniques
[link 2](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/) : Liquid layouts the easy way 
[link 3](http://perishablepress.com/the-5-minute-css-mobile-makeover/) : The 5-Minute CSS Mobile Makeover

Hope, these links will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would detect the useragent, and then display the correct UI depending on the device.  I do this in my jQuery Mobile app (although I don't use PhoneGap) with PHP.

Comment: thank you for the response. So in your scenario are you able to reuse any of the presentation logic across the smartphone app and tablet app? I am sure the JS is being reused, but how about the UI?
Also, are you having to anything special to take into account of the 7 inch tablets and 10 inch?